# Vue.js VS Code template syntax highlight is broken?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing some strange highlight behavior with VS Code in a Vue.js template. When there is a double quote `"` opening and closing on multiple lines, the highlight after the second double quote is still consider as a string. Example in image below :

[image]

Does anyone knows how to make sure VS Code understand that it's a closing double quote ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not this problem on my side. Did you install Vetur?

Comment: @Zooly yes i installed Vetur. Maybe something in the configuration i missed ?

Comment: I don't think, i have no specific config on Vetur.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically ESlint breaking Vetur because of it's formatting. Maybe try to update to the latest version of ESlint or export it to a `methods` hook.

Or increase the width in `.prettierrc`

```json
{
  "printWidth": 130
}
```

Sub-optimal I recognize.